# How to add form control to specific control

Tags: angular, forms

How do I add new form control or form group to specific form control?

```
public SaleRequestForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        SaleToPOIRequest: new FormGroup({
          MessageHeader: new FormGroup({
            MessageType: new FormControl(''),
            MessageClass: new FormControl(''),
            MessageCategory: new FormControl(''),
            SaleID: new FormControl(''),
            POIID: new FormControl(''),
            ProtocolVersion: new FormControl(''),
            ServiceID: new FormControl(''),
          })
    })
```

I image it would look something like this.

```
this.SaleRequestForm.controls.MessageHeader.addControl('test', new FormControl());
```

I've been googling and googling but I can't seem to find an answer

Comment: something like this ? `this.SaleRequestForm.get("SaleToPOIRequest").get("MessageHeader").addControl(new FormControl('foo', null))`. Also, please use camelCase when naming variables, not PascalCase...

Comment: @Random It works but I'm looking for a bit easier way to do it. This way I have to go down the tree, I'd like to just target one form control like this : this.SaleRequestForm.controls.MessageHeader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thought is right, but just will appear in angular if you cast the object with FormGroup, like this:

```js
(this.SaleRequestForm.get("SaleToPOIRequest.MessageHeader") as FormGroup).addControl("test", new FormControl())
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jmvmdf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: This just give me error: Cannot read property 'addControl' of undefined ` :/

Comment: You need to change the name of the variable to your case: (this.objFormGroup.controls.MessageHeader as FormGroup).addControl("test", new FormControl())

Comment: I'll change my answer above for your understanding

Comment: I did change it don't worry :D. It gave me the error. Also you need to change it to this.saleRequestForm.controls if you want it to be precise but I don't care which way it is.

Comment: Sorry, now I find the error, I'll change again and send here as well xD

Comment: Can you try it, please?   ((this.objFormGroup.controls.SaleToPOIRequest as FormGroup).controls.MessageHeader as FormGroup).addControl("test", new FormControl())

Comment: please, to "get" the formGroup use "get":`(this.objFormGroup.get('MessageHeader') as FormGroup).addControl(....)` not directtly controls.MessageHeader

Comment: @GabrielSereno got this error now :Cannot read property 'MessageHeader' of undefined :/

Comment: @Eliseo got this error trying it : Cannot read property 'addControl' of null. It will work if I do it like Random commented but as I replied to his comment I'm looking for a way to do like your writing, with one command to target it.

Comment: @C0mpl3x, I'll create a stackblitz for you, wait a moment

Comment: Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jmvmdf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @GabrielSereno Thank you. I was looking for a bit simpler way to do it but I think it is not possible so your solution is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it step by step:

```
const saleToPOIRequest: FormGroup = this.SaleRequestForm?.get("SaleToPOIRequest") as FormGroup;
const messageHeader: FormGroup = saleToPOIRequest?.get("MessageHeader") as FormGroup;
if (messageHeader) {
  const myNewFormControl = new FormControl(null);
  messageHeader.addControl("foo", myNewFormControl);
}
```